# Wix .NET Custom Action running in 64 bit context

Tags: .net, 64-bit, wix, custom-action

I've created a Wix (3.0) custom action written in .NET. Fine.

The problem is that I shall access to the Windows registry during the execution of the custom action, but I have a redirection on the Wow6432Node...

Looking for something useful in the log file of the MSI installation, I found the following log lines:

> Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
>
> SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIB858.tmp-\
>
> SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v2.0.50727
>
> Calling custom action DemoLicenceCA!DemoLicenceCA.CustomActions.InstallDemoLicences

Of course, if the nice custom action server would run at 64 bit I could avoid this boring problem of registry rediction.

How is it possible to workaround this limitation?

---

The MSI package is built for 64 bit platform. The custom action DLL is build for any platform (CLI), and the MSI package is installing on Windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is sufficient to force the build platform to x86 or x64 to run in the right context. That's a pity, since I have to manage two configuration instead of a single one, but this is not a big problem.